# How can we enable Transport layer Security in Hive metastore?

Tags: tls1.2, thrift

I need to know how to enable Transport layer security in Hive Metastore and how to verify it. Should we create another .xml file specifying the property? This should be based on Thrift url.

I tried to edit two files in hive-metastore by specifying the properties -metastore-site.xml and conf-site.xml. And I am getting the following error even after creating the keys:

```
[root@primmer1 lh-hms-poc]# openssl s_client -connect 9.30.94.163:9083 -cert cert.crt -key cert.key
CONNECTED(00000003)
139828257847184:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 289 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1672830872
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```